# Exception with Graphs Generator

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

JMeter version - 2.13
I have following plugins in my JMeter installation -

[image]

And was wanting to generate graphs for a previously run test -

[image]

But I end up with following exception -

```
2015/12/29 13:45:15 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/cmd/UniversalRunner
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.<init>(PluginsCMDWorker.java:52)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:146)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:226)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:448)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Did I misconfigure plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add CMDRunner-1.3.1.jar in lib/ext folder:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/

It's in the Standard bundle.